# Centering a form in css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a form that I cannot center. I have tried many things including :

```
form{
     display:inline-block;
     text-align:center;
     margin:auto;
}
```

the dang thing won't center though. help please?

URL: http://s1527.mtchs.org/wordpress/contact/

Comment: Specify a width and then use `margin: 0 auto;` - and keep in mind `text-align` only applies to [block containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/text.html#propdef-text-align)

Answer (score 4):

```
form {
    width: 50%; /* adjust as needed */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Block-level elements are centred by setting the left and right margins to the same value - in general the easiest way to do this is to set them both to `auto`. `text-align` on the other hand, applies to inline elements inside the element you apply the style to.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with margins should work. Set a top/bottom margin for your element and the rest auto and it should center it automatically.

```
margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna use display: inline-block and text-align combination, then you have to put text-align in the parent element
example

```
<div style="position: relative; display: block; text-align: center">
   <div style="display: inline-block">
</div>
```

OR

you can simply put width in the from css

```
form{
     display:block;
     margin:auto;
     width:600px;
}
```